# Is there a way to use _T/TEXT "conditionally" inside a macro?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, unicode, wchar-t, tchar

This question is specific to Visual C++ (you may assume Visual C++ 2005 and later).

I would like to create glue code for a program from unixoid systems (FreeBSD in particular) in order build and run on Win32 with a minimum of changes to the original `.c` file. Now, most of this is straightforward, but now I ran into an issue. I am using the `tchar.h` header and `TCHAR`/`_TCHAR` and need to create glue code for the `err` and `errx` calls (see [`err(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/err.3.html)) in the original code. Bear with me, even if you don't agree that code using `tchar.h` should still be written.

The calls to `err` and `errx` take roughly two forms, and this is where the problem occurs:

```
err(1, "some string with %d format specifiers and %s such", ...)
/* or */
err(1, NULL, ...)
```

The latter would output the error stored in `errno` (using `strerror`).

Now, the question is, is there any way to write a generic macro that can take both `NULL` and a string literal? I do not have to (and *will not*) care about *variables* getting passed as the second parameter, only `NULL` and literal strings.

Of course my naive initial approach didn't account for `fmt` passed as `NULL` (using variadic macros!):

```
#define err(eval, fmt, ...) my_err(eval, _T(fmt), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Right now I don't have any ideas how to achieve this with macros, because it would require a kind of mix of compile-time and runtime conditionals that I cannot imagine at the moment. So I am looking for an authoritative answer whether this is conceivable at all or not.

The method I am resorting to right now - lacking a better approach - is to write a wrapper function that accepts, just like `err` and `errx`, a (`const`) `char *` and then converting that to `wchar_t *` if compiled with `_UNICODE` defined. This should work, assuming that the caller passes a `_TCHAR*` string for the variable arguments after the `fmt` (which is a sane assumption in my context). Otherwise I'd also have to convert `%s` to `%hs` inside the format string, to handle "ANSI" strings, as MS calls them.

Comment: FWIW, you could improve matters marginally by using a direct #define for err if _UNICODE is not defined, and only including the wrapper function if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifdef _UNICODE

#define LNULL NULL
#define fn(x) myfn(L ## x)

#else

#define fn(x) myfn(x)

#endif

void myfn(TCHAR * str)
{
    if (str == NULL) _tprintf(_T("<NULL>")); else _tprintf(str);
    _tprintf(_T("\n"));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    fn("hello");
    fn(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a clever method. Thanks!